# can't db:migrate after installing Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I installed Paperclip just now and I can no longer run rake db:migrate.

The migration

```
class AddPaperclipToProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
        add_attachment :posts, :image  

  end
end
```

The model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200", xlarge: "300x300" }

end
```

Here's the error

```
== 20151224145355 AddPaperclipToProfiles: migrating ===========================
-- add_attachment(:posts, :image)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: posts: ALTER TABLE "posts" ADD "image_file_name" varchar/Users/RichieSiegel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to add image to `posts`?  I guess you should change

```
add_attachment :posts, :image
```

to:

```
add_attachment :profiles, :image
```